# How to develop E-commerce App for Android?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Mobile Apps Development. Now I'm interest to develop a M-Commerce App. But I don't have any idea how to start where to learn. can anyone suggest me where can I study M-Commerce for Android development?  Is it easy to develop? what are all the language I need to know to develop M-commerce? How long it takes to complete?

Comment: this site is for helping your programming problems. not for teach you how to program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have deep knowledge about E-Commerce/M-Commerce app development. But here's a thing that can get you started:

1. To start with Android development follow the official docs. Follow the link: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html
2. There are various tutorial on Android development all over YouTube that can help you a lot.
3. You need to learn JAVA. JAVA basics are must to start with android development.
4. Don't directly jump for high level programming just like game development or M-Commerce app . Start with basic app and slowly progress in different parts of android development.
5. If you are looking forward for cross platform development then take a look at C# language and develop app in Visual Studio or Xamarin.